# How do i create a pdf document with unique id for each pdf on a website?

Tags: pdf, dynamic, unique

on a website i am creating, i want to have a pdf link that when clicked will present to the user a pdf document with a uniquly generated ID. 
Basically i want to create a link that creates a time sheet for user to either print or download.

I have the general template for the time sheet in PDf and Jpeg format. i just need to figure out how to automatically/dynamically stamp/tag each time sheet template with a unique ID before presenting it to user for download or printing.

Comment: What if you create the PDF in run time?, so every time someone need the PDF, you create it and put the unique id or whatever the info you need ?

Comment: not clear what programming language are you using to generate the code and what have you tried

Comment: thanks for the response. i have used fpdf library, i am able to generated the unique code and the pdf page dynamically. i imported a jpg template of the timesheet/reciept into the dynamically created pdf. The problem i am facing is making the unique ID to go on top of the imported template. The unique id is going on a new line.

Comment: <?php
require("fpdf/fpdf.php");
$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Image('timesheet_template.jpg');
$pdf->SetFont("Arial", "B","12");
$pdf->Cell(10,10,"ABC6548340",0,0,C);
$pdf->output();
?>

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution, i had to combine the fpdf library as well as the fpdi library. fpdi library is a Free PDF Document Importer library, its like an improvement to the already existing fpdf library. Fpdi library along with many other features allow you to import a pdf document and simply stamp it with any text, watermark etc of your choice. problem solved with just a few lines of code, thanks to all the geniuses coming up with these libraries and giving it away for free. :)